# Can I choose a different identicon without uploading one as a profile picture?

Tags: support, profile-picture, gravatar

I was trying to change the identicon. It is allowing me to upload new photos as per my wish.

I want to change the current identicon. Can we choose our own identicon (without uploading any pictures)?

If yes, can you please let me know how to change this?

Comment: You mean to choose out of the predefined (which are assigned randomly to new users)?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: @SivaaNethaji please don't remove the [meta-tag:gravatar] tag, the identicon is generated by gravatar.com e.g. https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4358bbc7133827200916d9b5c760a1b7?s=60&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1 so it's relevant

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't change the identicon unless you change the e-mail address you have in your profile. It's derived from the e-mail address in some way (I'm assuming the algorithm is semi secret so you can't reverse engineer the address easily from the image).

This means that while you'll get another image it will be random again.

If you have a particular pattern you like just upload that as the image.

Comment: if I change the email address. Can we choose our own Icon or it will be assigned randomly again?

Comment: @SivaaNethaji - it will be assigned randomly again.

Comment: Semi-secret? Like md5? Most people use md5s from what I've heard.

Comment: Yes, it's not as much semi-secret as it is non-reversible.

Comment: Keeping the algorithm semi-secret in order to prevent decryption of e-mail address would contravene the [Kerckhoffs's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Comment: What if I change my address to fake one and then bring back the original. Will I get the same old icon or a new one?

Comment: @ChrisF you can read about the [md5 hash](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/) on the gravatar website